# Why are edits on some posts closed?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

Why are edits on some posts closed?For instance-[Factor Theorem and Long Division](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537103/factor-theorem-long-division)

Edit tab cannot be clicked here.Why is it blocked? I have seen this in many other questions.

Comment: You can find a few related older posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6480

Comment: FYI, if you let your mouse hover over the edit link, there's a tooltip explaining what's going on. (It happens sufficiently often on the internet that it's a useful habit to take.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a post has a [pending edit suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/126134), it cannot be edited until that suggestion was approved or rejected. If you have more than 2k rep, you will be shown a link to review the pending suggestion, below 2k, you just can't edit the post.

Comment: Here also I can't edit your post.Why?

Comment: @tatan Hovering over grayed out "edit" link tells you why: "suggested edits are disabled on meta sites", i.e., here. Meta is a different site with different rules; only users with 2000+ reputation can edit here.